# create cic cd pipeline for multiple projects for single bitbucket repository in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I am trying to build ci cd pipeline in gitlab for our bitbucket repository. There are two projects in single bitbucket repository frontend (angular) and backend (.net core). I am trying to build gitlab pipeline for that project. But  how to write gitlab-ci.yaml to build, test and deploy for ci cd pipeline. There are no option to write .gitlab-ci.yaml for both project. Repository hierarchy is given below:

there are two folder web(frontend project- angular) and backend (backend project- .net core)
[image: Frontend project named (web) and Backend project named (backend)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with [parent-child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html).

So in your pipeline you build the frontend part and then call the pipeline for the backend part.

```
stages:
  - frontend
  - backend

frontend:
  stage: frontend
  script:
    - echo "build frontend"

backend:
  stage: backend
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'tutorsinc'
        file: '.build-backend.yml'
    strategy: depend
```